# What IP does a website see when sending request from backend?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services

I have a website that gets the client's question from my react web and finds the matched question on chegg and sends the answer to the client.
I was wondering does chegg only sees one  ip since all the request goes through from my server or they see the client's IP as the visitor ?

Comment: it sees single ip of your server

Comment: If you use ELB, it will be one of IPs of the ELBs nodes.

Comment: @Marcin the question seems to be about a third-party web site that OP's server is scraping "from the backend," which might be a TOS violation, hence the IP being relevant.

Comment: Chegg doesn't seem to allow what's being contemplated, here.  [*"You will not use, copy, adapt, modify, prepare derivative works based upon, distribute, license, sell, transfer, publicly display, publicly perform, transmit, stream, broadcast or otherwise exploit the Site, Services or Collective Content, except as expressly permitted in these Tutor Terms of Service."*](https://www.chegg.com/tutoringterms)